# Defining a function inside a template literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, template-literals, styled-components

I'm using [styled-components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) as a solution to styling for React. They've got a nice approach that uses template literals to interpolate CSS. The template literals are passed the component's props so that you can do things like:

```js
const PasswordsMatchMessage = styled.div`
    background: ${props => props.isMatching ? 'green' : 'red'};
`
```

The result is a component that renders a `div` tag with either a green or red background depending on the value of `isMatching`. The above would be used via JSX like this:

```js
<PasswordsMatchMessage isMatching={doPasswordsMatch}>...</PasswordsMatchMessage>
```

Every time the value of `props` changes, this string is going to be re-interpolated. Which finally brings me to my question:

**Does the arrow function defined inside the template literal get re-defined every time the template literal is interpolated?**

If so, then I may consider creating functions outside the template literal and just passing those in, e.g.

```js
const PasswordsMatchMessage = styled.div`
    background: ${isMatchingFn};
`
```

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work. Have you tested it?

Comment: @KeithA it does work, that's not my question. I just edited my post to make the question clearer since it was a bit buried ;)

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not sure. Is there is a reason for your question?

Comment: It would be a potential performance bottleneck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it would define a new version of the function each time the template literal is interpolated. You can verify that by defining your own tag that keeps track of the previous value.

```
var previous;
function trackInterpolations(literalParts, interpolated) {
  if (interpolated === previous) {
    answer = 'Got the same function';
  } else {
    answer = 'Got a different function';
  }
  previous = interpolated;
  return answer;
}
```

Then run

```
trackInterpolations`background: ${props => props.isMatching ? 'green' : 'red'};`
```

a couple of times and notice that it always evaluates to `'Got a different function'`, indicating that it's creating a new function each time.

Compare that to this version:

```
trackInterpolations`background: ${isMatchingFn};`
```

The first time it's run, it will evaluate to `'Got a different function'` (because it hasn't seen the `isMatchingFn` yet), but if you evaluate it a few more times it will always result in `'Got the same function'`, because the function reference is being reused.

I wouldn't worry too much about the performance impact though in this case, and go with whatever is more readable unless you actually notice a slowdown. Compared to re-rendering the div, the overhead of creating a new function isn't likely to be very high.

Comment: I think you mean to say that even running it the second time still results in `Got a different function` -- otherwise, it would mean that the function was not getting redefined, thus contradicting your answer. I also tried it out and indeed, it says that it's a different function each time :). In regards to performance bottlenecks, no, I'm not going to worry about it now. But this kind of template literal usage was new to me so I wanted to make sure I understood what was going on.

Comment: @maxedison After reading it again, that part isn't very clear, because it's talking about two different expressions. And yes, in some cases, there could be performance implications, so it's good to know :)